# Recursive for loop in batch files without following symlinks

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there an easy way in batch files to loop over files including subdirs like bellow, except **without following symlinks**?

```
FOR /R %%F IN (*) DO (...)
```

I haven't seen such flag in `for` help...

The context is I'm writing a batch file that loops over files and creates symlinks. It needs to go through subdirs, however when there are symlinks targeting dirs, it should not go through them. With my current `FOR /R` loop implementation, the problem is that it treats such symlinks as subdirs and runs the script in their target's contents. I don't care whether the solution excludes symlinks to plain files (as opposed to dirs).

Thanks for your help

**EDIT for clarification:**

For instance, provided this directory structure :

```
dir
 |-- A.txt
 |-- subDir
 |     |-- B.txt
 |-- linkDir = symlink to targetDir
 |-- Z.txt = symlink to targetDir/C.txt

targetDir
 |-- C.txt
```

When I run the `FOR /R` loop on `dir`, it processes `A.txt` and `B.txt` as expected, but also `C.txt` which I don't want. This is because the `FOR /R` instruction follows symlinks when building the list of files to iterate over, so it acts as if `linkDir` were a regular sub-directory which contains `C.txt`.

Regarding `Z.txt`, it doesn't matter whether the loop read it. The `FOR /R` implementation actually processes it but I've set up a filter to skip iteration when `%%F` is a symlink.

Problem is I don't know how to tell `FOR` not to include `C.txt` in the list, nor when `%%F` is `targetDir\C.txt` how to know that this file is in the list because it followed the symlink in path `dir\subDir\C.txt`.

Comment: Try the `ATTRIB` command over the files/dirs. Check the `/L` switch...

Comment: `FOR /F "EOL=? DELIMS=" %%F IN ('DIR /B /S /A:-L') DO …` You may also wish to look at the other options for the `DIR` command, i.e. open up a Command Prompt window and enter `dir /?`.

Comment: @Aacini Isn't `ATTRIB` just for changing attributes?

Comment: @Compo That's a good try, that excludes symlinks to plain files, but unfortunately the `/S` flag still follows symlinks...

Comment: @fbastien, given that you've provided only a very limited idea of what you're trying to achieve, it isn't possible for me to be more specific. What happens when you use other options too, as mentioned in my previous comment? e.g. `FOR /F "EOL=? DELIMS=" %%F IN ('DIR /B /S /A:-D-S-L') DO …`

Comment: The `ATTRIB` command can just _show_ the attributes, so you may check they in each file/dir.

Comment: @Compo I edited my question to add an example, hope this makes it clearer. Using my example, `DIR /A:-L` successfully excludes `Z.txt` but the `/S` flag doesn't check for sub-directories attributes when going through them. I.e. it checks whether `A.txt`, `B.txt`, `C.txt` and `Z.txt` are symlinks, but it doesn't check whether `subDir` and `linkDir` are symlinks. I want the loop not to enter `linkDir` thus not processing `C.txt`

Comment: @Aacini Right, thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately `ATTRIB /S /D` shows no difference between regular and symlinked files (both only have `A` attribute) nor between regular and symlinked directories (both have no attribute flag). I can't see any difference adding the `/L` flag to `ATTRIB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own recurse function, checking each file/directory for links.
It's a bit slow, because of the `%%~aX` access for each file/directory.

```
@echo off

call :recurseDir .
exit /b

:recurseDir
rem echo ----- :recurseDir "%~1" -------
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~1"
FOR /F "delims=" %%X in ('dir /b') DO (
    set "attr=%%~aX"

    if "!attr:~8,1!" NEQ "l" (
        if "!attr:~0,1!" EQU "d" (
            call :recurseDir "%%~fX"
        ) ELSE (
            call echo :processFile "%%~fX"
        )
    )
)
popd
```

To speed it up, you could split the logic for files and directories.
Then it's only necessary to check directories with `%%~aX` for symlinks.
This version doesn't need delayed expansion anymore, because it's detects symlinks by splitting the attributes at the character `l` in `d-------l--`.
Because Win 7 shows only `d-------l`, it's necessary to append at least one dummy character to the attributes (I choose `#`)

```
@echo off

call :recurseDir .
exit /b

:recurseDir
echo ----- :recurseDir "%~1" -------
pushd "%~1"
FOR /F "delims=" %%X in ('dir /b /a:-l-d 2^> nul') DO (
    call echo :processFile "%%~fX"
)
FOR /D %%X in (*) DO (  
    set "symlink="
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=l" %%A in ("%%~aX #") DO set "symlink=1"
    if not defined symlink (
        call :recurseDir "%%~fX"
    )
)
popd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! I had to tweak the second version though because the `symlink` variable was never set to 1 and `pushd` threw an error when given a symlink. My fix was to add a random character after `%%~aX` in the nested loop. I guess that's because the `l` character is the last one in the attributes list, so even when it's present, the second token would be empty and the `for` command would ignore it. I'm waiting a bit to see if someone comes up with a solution without subroutines before I accept your answer.

Comment: I'm astonished that `l` is the last character in your attribute list! My list looks like `d-------l--` for a symlink (Win 10.0.17134.1006), which version you are using? But your solution to add a character at `"%%~aX` should work. I just changed my answer for that case

Comment: I'm wondering why `pushd <symlink>` fails in your case, because thats works for me without problems. But still it isn't important for your problem, as you don't want to follow symlinks at all. Are you sure your symlink points to an existing directory?

Comment: I'm using Win7 SP1. And yeah, my fault for `pushd <symlink>` failing: I was using relative paths and used slashes instead of backward slash... ^^

Comment: @fbastien I've checked with Win7 and found the behaviour you described, there are less  attributes. Also `attrib /?` has fewer options

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /R /D %%f in (*) do (
   set "attr=%%~Af"
   if "!attr:~8,1!" neq "l" (
      echo Files in this not-symlink dir:
      dir /B /A:-D "%%f"
   )
)
```

Comment: Is a good solution in many cases, but has the drawback, that the symlinked directories are searched completely. That can even result into a deadlock when a symlink points to a *parent* directory

Comment: It's not a valid solution to my problem, as it outputs the contents of `targetDir` (i.e. `C.txt`). The difficult part here is not to exclude symlinks targeting plain files, but excluding files in sub-directories that have been accessed through symlinked directories.

Comment: I found the problem of this solution. It detects a symlink directory, but child directories of a symlink dir are treated as *valid* directories. So it only works, when a symlink dir, doesn't have any child directories